# The more images I add to an infinite scrollview the smaller they get

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make a reader app in kivy. I'm having trouble displaying images in a scrollview. The more images I add the smaller they get.

Is there some kind of dynamic way I can get the images no matter what size to fit the full screen?

I do have some code but at this point rather scrap it. Size hint on the y axis seems to do something but I wanna see if there's a better way.

```
import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from PIL import Image as Image1
path = 'F:\\manga\\A Strange Life\\1\\'
Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
Window.size = (1000, 200)
class MainApp(App):
    def images_size(self,img_size, **kwargs):
        width, height = Window.size
        return width, (img_size[0] * height / width)
    def build(self):
        root = ScrollView(size=(Window.width,Window.height))
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1,size_hint=(1,None),height=self.minimum_height)
        for i in range(1,len(os.listdir(path))+1):
            img_size = Image1.open(f'{path}{str(i)}.jpg').size
            img = AsyncImage(source=f'{path}{str(i)}.jpg',nocache=True)
            layout.add_widget(img) 
        root.add_widget(layout)
        return root

MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that the code:

```
layout = GridLayout(cols=1,size_hint=(1,None),height=self.minimum_height)
```

will fail because at that point `self.minimum_height` is attempting to access the `minimum_height` property of `MainApp` (which does not exist). Using `minimum_height` is what you need to do, but you would need to bind code to set the `height` of the `GridLayout` whenever its `minimum_height` changes. However, if you use the kivy language, that binding is created for you automatically. Here is a `kv` language string that does this:

```
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window
ScrollView:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: Window.size
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        cols: 1
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height
```

And then you can add `Images` to the `GridLayout` by accessing it through the `grid` id. Here is a modified version of your code that does all of the above:

```
import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.core.window import Window
from PIL import Image as Image1
path = 'F:\\manga\\A Strange Life\\1\\'
Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
Window.size = (1000, 200)

kv = '''
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window
ScrollView:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: Window.size
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        cols: 1
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height
'''
class MainApp(App):
    def images_size(self,img_size, **kwargs):
        width, height = Window.size
        return width, (img_size[0] * height / width)
    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_string(kv)
        layout = root.ids.grid
        for i in range(1,len(os.listdir(path))+1):
            img_size = Image1.open(f'{path}{str(i)}.jpg').size
            img = AsyncImage(source=f'{path}{str(i)}.jpg',nocache=True, size_hint=(None, None), size=img_size)
            layout.add_widget(img)
        return root

MainApp().run()
```